# Using .NET desktop application with DevExpress over Remote Desktop

Tags: .net, winforms, delphi, devexpress, remote-desktop

I ported a Delphi desktop application to .NET(C#). 
Both of them are using DevExpress components and they have to be used over Remote Destop connection.

Remote Desktop connection is a slow connection. 
When both are tested over Remote Desktop; Delphi application seems to be much more faster then .NET one.

In .NET the pages are opening part by part like a web page laoding but i want the page to be loaded in one portion.

Can i achieve this?

PS. I used UserControl component of DevExpress as pages(tabs).

PPS. I dismissed the fade in and fade out effects of loading and splash screen components for speeding up.​

Delphi application screen video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mHHDsqe5Dg&feature=youtu.be

.NET application screen video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7N-FEcVoLQ&feature=youtu.be

**Some More Details:**

[image: Sales Processing PAge as UserControl component]

This is one of the most complex pages in the application. It's "XtraUserControl" User Control implementation of DevExpress(Basically the same with winforms User Control).

I used LayoutControl > LayoutControlGroup > LayoutControlItem components of DevExpress for aligning the components(grids, button, text boxes etc.) on the user Control.

And here is the Main Container for User Controls(Pages like above):

[image: MAin Container as Form for containing the User Controls(Pages)]

The main container for Tabs(User Controls like this one) is a "XtraForm" Form implementration of DevExpress. When a Menu Item is selected from the Container form, the related UserControl(Page) is loaded on the Main Container Form as a Tab item and user can navigate between tabs or open a new page(User Control) from Menu.

Comment: Have you tried to create native images of your .Net application with [NGEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx) tool?

Comment: No, i didn't know about it. Seems to be helpful for the problem. I will check and respond.

Comment: Hard to say what's happening. Somebody who knew what the two apps were doing, how they were implemented and which controls were used is needed to make progress. At the moment that's you. Until you supply some real detail, you are on your own.

Comment: @DmitryG what makes you think that the jitter is the bottleneck?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this is only idea, but this is first what i'll try to do before performance comparison of native(Delphi) and managed(.Net) applications... And often the results are magical

Comment: @DmitryG Really? Surely this can only help for code that runs once. Rendering code runs over and over.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it also removes yet another problem with ugly performance of WinForms application compiled as x64/AnyCPU comparing with applications compiled as x86 on 64-bit OS

Comment: Yet another idea - simply build your .Net solution as `x86` (Not `AnyCPU` as it specified by default). [JFYI - AnyCPU Exes are usually more trouble than they're worth](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/8/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx)

Comment: I'm trying your offered solutions. Moreover i updated my question with some more details. If any further detail is needed i can provide.

Comment: @DmitryG what, performance of gui rendering is better under the wow64 emulator? Nothing you say makes any sense. Do you have any evidence?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The fact that applications may be slower if built for x64 is confirmed by some component vendors - for example, by [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/general/building-applications-for-x64-or-anycpu-at-64-bit-os.aspx). This issue can be easily reproduced by executing a big number of complex operations(as far as i can see in the original video, the performance of layout calculations is bad, not the GUI rendering). And yes, in most real-world scenarios running .Net application in the WOW is faster than running as x64 - just try it yourself.

Comment: @DmitryG Perhaps you haven't absorbed the fact that the question is about performance over RDP. You might like to read the question again.

Comment: @gesus You are comparing apples and pears. The Delphi control is simply different to the .net control. Quite possibly the rendering frameworks differ too. And maybe your apps are sufficiently different. In any case, despite what Dmitry says, there's no magic switch to solve your problem. The issue is the amount of traffic over the remote connection. Dmitry suggests that you compile before loading, and run under WOW64. But those suggestions seem unrelated to the issue of network traffic. If you want
your app to work better under rdp, I suggest you talk to
devexpress. They are the ones that unde

Comment: that understand how their controls work. Did you contact them yet?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm sorry, David. It appears that there was some misunderstanding with this issue from my side. Thank you for pointing me into right direction. Yesterday I've spent several hours researching this issue from RDP-specifics side and it seems I guess the possible reasons now. Please accept my apologies for my comments which could cause any inconvenience. I'm loving .Net so much))

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I talked with DevExpress team and they suggest using Ngen. I'm not familiar with it but working on it. But i'm not sure how it'll help me. If it loads tha main page as an image or can i arrange it to open the tabs as images?

Comment: @gesus I cannot see how Ngen could help. I suggest you point them to my comments in this thread and ask them to consider your request more seriously. If they suggest Ngen then they aren't trying hard enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm working with DevExpress .Net controls (and moreover sometimes with their controls source code) since 2007. And it seems I know the possible reasons of visual drawback of these controls under RDP.
These reasons are:
 - **Skinning technology** (which is bitmap-based)
 - **Double-buffered painting**

So, let me explain. When the user is connected via a Remote Desktop Connection, all drawing operations performed by control are transferred over the network connection to the RDP client for display. If control draw a line, the "DrawLine" command is sent over the network to the client. If control draw a text, a "DrawText" command is sent (along with the text to draw).
But if control draw a bitmap, the entire bitmap needs to be transferred over the network. Thus this can be a main bottleneck when using low-bandwidth connection.

The double-buffered painting is based on performing all drawing operation into an offscreen bitmap. Then this bitmap is copying onto screen with using [BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. This technique is used in DevExpress controls to draw various visual effects and smooth animations. This avoid any flickering in controls when control's elements are redrawn quickly and also is used for drawing skinned control elements (more details below). 
But when RDP is used the BitBlt-operation is also transferred over the network as the entire bitmap thus this is a problem when using low-bandwidth connection.

The [DevExpress Skinning technology](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2534) is bitmap based. A skin is a set of bitmaps that determine how control elements should be painted in all its possible states (normal, hot-tracked, selected, pressed, etc.). When control paint itself, it draw these bitmaps, - element by element. It allow DevExpress controls to be so beauty and pixel-perfect.
I see from your video and screenshots that **your .Net application is used skins (and it seems that the concrete skin is the "DevExpress Style") but your Delphi/VCL application is not skinned**. Is it true? I believe, yes. So the possible way to reduce the drawback of your application is disabling skinning for forms and using Flat Style for control:

```
// .NET application, Program.cs
...
DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.DisableFormSkins();
DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.DisableMdiFormSkins();
DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default.SetFlatStyle();
...
```

Related help topics: [Look And Feel Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument776), [Look and Feel Mechanism](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2409)

I should also note that the Flat-painting is not double-buffered, thus it is may be a possible solution for slow RDP connections.

Important Exceptions: Some DevExpress controls does not supports Flat-painting (for example RibbonControl). I know that the LayoutControl, the XtraGrid and most of XtraEditors are supports flat-painting. You should contact DevExpress directly about the another controls.

P.S. @David Heffernan: Thank you for pointing me into right direction.
P.P.S. 
All things i've mentioned in comments erlier are true things which can increase an application performace at application startup and in general. But these things is unrelated to the original problem with network traffic.

**UPDATE**
Related DevExpress Support Article:
[How to speed up Windows Forms applications, running in a Remote Desktop Services (formerly known as Terminal Services) environment](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2034?searchtext=remote%20desktop)

Comment: +1 This is much more like it! Quite plausible that the advice here can help. I'd like to add one comment. Your app can (and should) detect that it is running in a remote session. When it detects that it should switch to the bandwidth friendly rendering. That way you can retain the nice visuals when running locally, but have the performance when running remote.

Comment: +1 for David's comment. To check whether or not your app is running under RDP check the [SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.terminalserversession.aspx) property

Comment: @DmitryG I'll try your solutions and i guess Ngen won't make any diffference to my problem?

Comment: @gesus yes, NGen won't affect the things related to the original problem with network traffic.

Comment: Actually the Delphi version also has skin. In the ComboBox upper right you can select sking for both delphi and .NET. I made some tests on RDP connection for both and calculate the flowing data via WireShark. It seems that on Delphi less data is flowing. When i dismissed skin on .NET the flowing data also reduced.

Comment: I added skins via `defaultLookAndFeelSelectSkin.LookAndFeel.SetSkinStyle(loadedSkin);` and when the user selects another skin, `defaultLookAndFeelSelectSkin` is set to that. I'm calling these in `MainContainerForm` that is after calling `// .NET application, Program.cs
...
DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.DisableFormSkins();
DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.DisableMdiFormSkins();
DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default.SetFlatStyle();
...`

Comment: To avoid using skins when running via RDP do not call the LookAndFeel.SetSkinStyle at all, (e.g. you can hide the skin selector ComboBox)

Comment: I called 
SkinManager.DisableMdiFormSkins();
but the thing is i'm using user controls as pages and loading them in a TabbedView as tabs.
How can i disable skin of UserControl's?

Comment: There were some heavy pages on the application and i made them preloading on start up and appearing when called. This made some progress. But actually using without skin did not make so much difference and do you think creating a very light skin will not either?